# Why were children photographed In Crete, Greece around mid-late 1940's photos with the stamp on the back “A M Crown Copyright Reserved”?

Tags: greece, civil-war, children

I have a few old photos from about the mid to late 1940's in Crete, Greece (the civil war occurred during the time). There is a specific stamp on the back of two photos which is marked A M Crown Copyright Reserved. Any guesses why only the children were photographed by the British photographers?

One photo is a family (my relatives) who were kids and teenagers then, standing close together looking straight into the camera as if they were told to stand like that with their arms down next to their sides. They were not smiling. And a few looked "concerned" in the photos. Before recently, I thought it was a "family" photo. But now I am not so sure. Maybe it was a family photo.

Furthermore, the other small picture I have with the same stamp on the back is only of the small boy from the other photo. He is standing in front of some kind of painted or printed mural on a cloth backdrop that shows a scene of a column, stairs, stair rails, and a wooden look image in the back of a wall.

I did some research and all I could find is that the British forces and photographers were in Greece at that time and it wasn't the best of times.

I found this info:

> "The A crown M was the copyright mark of the Air Ministry, now ministry of Defence. I was a photographer in the RAF and all photographs had to be stamped on the reverse" *[ephotozine.com](https://www.ephotozine.com/forums/topic/crown-copyright-51017)*

[image: Two photos; first shows a family, second shows a small child]